# Autofac автоматический resolve appsetting

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, autofac

В моём проекте ASP.NET Web API имеется настройка для Autofac, для резолва конфига.

```
    var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

    var resolver = new EnvironmentJsonResolver<Config>("appsettings.json", $"appsettings.{env}.json");
    var module = new ConfigurationModule(resolver);

    builder.RegisterModule(module);
```

Внутри класса Config содержатся следующие строки:

```
    public AuthOptions Auth { get; set; }

    public AttachmentOptions Attachments { get; set; }
```

Приложение крутится на серваке внутри Docker контейнера под Ubuntu.

Проблема в том, что резолвится только первая строка конфига. Т.е. Внутри appsettings.Production.json есть Auth и Attachments, но заполняется только первый из них. А второй в свою очередь при вызове в конструкторе вызывает ошибку.

Я пробовал менять их местами и это зависит только от того какой первый стоит.

Так же дело в том что под Windows в дебаг режиме всё работает хорошо! Проблема именно в контейнере на проде такая с первым из них.